# XmlReader.Create outputs none

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, xml-parsing

So I am trying to make RSS reader in C# MVC, but I am stuck at retrieving data from RSS source. The method from the title always is none.

Here is the code:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=1000)]
    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        string url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news";
        var link = new Uri("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news");
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
            {
                String subject = item.Title.Text;
                String summary = item.Summary.Text;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        //Don't know how to produce the output yet
        return View();
    }
```

Can someoen help me with making the use of those functions?

@edit

So I made it almost work, it now gets me values in title/summary, but I am not sure how to output it to view (probably partialview).
New code:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=1000)]
    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        string url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news";
        var link = new Uri("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news");
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        while (reader.Read())
        {       
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

            foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
            {
                String subject = item.Title.Text;
                String summary = item.Summary.Text;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        //Don't know how to produce the output yet
        return View();
    }
```

@last edit
Anyone knows how to print it so it shows whole list? The values changes in title/summary as I said, but the output is only last item.

```
  return PartialView("_Bar");
```

and partial view:

```
<div class="row">

    <p>@ViewBag.tytul</p>
    <p>@ViewBag.opis</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this while (*`while (reader.Read())`*) loop

```
string url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
{
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        String subject = item.Title.Text;
        String summary = item.Summary.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I see. Could you look at how could I make the output so all the elements from foreach loop are shown in the view, and not only one? edit, as i tried making loop in the partial view it shown me the same item multiple times.

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama It is not different than having a list of `Items` and displaying them in some UI. You are using MVC, and this is the basic thing you should know. If not, read some docs before continuing your project.

Comment: It was really late in my timezone, the first thing I've after waking up was making a list :) But I've got a problem, and it's probably because of that Controller-View strategy. If I could print in my loop at controller it would be awesome, but I have to do this in View, so I've put my 4 lists (four lists) into ViewBags, but I cannot iterate throu them like item1 from list 1, then item1 from list 2, item1 from list 3, item1 from list 4, item 2 from list 1... etc., could you help me with this one?